# Create a packet generator using c#,java or c++

Tags: c#, java, c++

i want to create my own packet generator, so that i am able to create packets of TCP,ICMP (ping, echo), UDP. I also want to set all the headers of packet and control all the flags my self, i mean i want to turn on the flags like SYN,FIN etc. I don't have any idea how to start it..

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated..

P.S : i don't have any problem with C#,c++ or java, i am comfortable with all of them, so u can give implementation suggestions regarding to any of the above languages..
Thanks

regards

usama

Comment: low-level packet programming...it sounds like you need a `pcap` library in Java....try `jNetPcap` and see one of its examples here: http://jnetpcap.com/examples/sendpacket

Comment: Other than for curiousity, is there a reason you want to do this?

Comment: Yes looking into raw sockets sounds like the right way to go on windows. If I remember correctly raw sockets need admin privs to use(at least for some features).

Comment: @MattBall , i haven't done anything yet, i am just starting,  @eee thnx for the links, i will explore that, @Peter, it is part of my college project, actually the project is to launch Sync flooding attack, i didn't find anyway to change the Sync flag, using C#,Java [i have explored JPcap, and even with JPcap i don't have excess to Syn flag [connection request], i only want to send connection req. and then when server will reply connection ack, i will simply ignore that, the server waits for some time, and in that time i can send 1000's of request from zombie systems,

Comment: @larsman & @CodelnChaos , thnx for the suggestions, i will explore raw socket, i don't have issue of admin prev's ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of headers you can use to create your functions for creating packets:

```
#include<linux/if_ether.h>
#include<linux/ip.h>
#include<linux/udp.h>
```

Once the packets have been created use the following to transmit over the interface:

[socket()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/socket.html)
[bind()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bind.html)

Hope this helps to start!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the source for [JPerf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jperf/). It uses Java to create packets for bandwidth monitoring. Also http://iperf.sourceforge.net/